# Creating button with ng-repeat that has an array with functions

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects with two keys. Key `label` is for the text that will go on the button. And then `action`, which is a function I want to happen when a user clicks (`ng-click`) the button. When I do this, no error is thrown, however the function does not work :(

My js:

```
var myBtns = [{
    label: 'btn1',
    action: function() {
        alert('hi')
    }
}];
```

My html is inside a directive like this:

```
<button type="button" ng-repeat="aBtnInfo in myBtns" ng-click="aBtnInfo.action()">
     aBtnInfo.label
</button>
```

Here is a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ppe34vLj/1/

On the other hand if I try `<button ng-click="{{aBtnInfo.action}}">`, it throws this error:

>
"Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7BaBtnInfo.action%7D%7D&p4=%7BaBtnInfo.action%7D%7D"

Of  course in this situation my array is no longer a function a string:

```
var myBtns = [{
    label: 'btn1',
    action: '$scope.restore()'
}];
```

This simple fiddle shows this second case: http://jsfiddle.net/ppe34vLj/3/

Comment: shouldn't myBtns be exposed like `$scope.myBtns = ...` ?

Comment: Thanks @KevinFriedheim I summarized this code, but that is not the issue. Ill try to write a fiddle right now.

Comment: your question isn't clear, and your examples are broken, and this is leading to people posting answers that don't seem to actually be what you are needing help with.  You might want to rephrase your question, unless, indeed, the problem was a typo.

Comment: Thanks @Claies the problem wasnt a typo actually it was more that I was setting my array at the top. But I was defining the var below it, so that fixed it, but the answers are actually nice I learned some stuff here like sandboxed alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment above:

https://jsbin.com/vunevazita/1/edit?html,js,output

remember that the `view` needs to reference the `controller` via `$scope`

Comment: Thanks Kevin but my sitatuion is a bit different i created a fiddle and added it to topic post: http://jsfiddle.net/ppe34vLj/1/

Comment: see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ppe34vLj/2/  - your `ng-click` needs to call the function - not just reference it.

Comment: Ohhh my goodness gracious, thanks!!  Its late :P 11pm here :P Do you know why the second fiddle wouldnt work? http://jsfiddle.net/ppe34vLj/3/

Comment: yup - the function that is getting called is a string - not a function. (`action: 'restoreDefaults()'`)

Comment: Thanks very much Kevin!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your fiddle.
Here's the [updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/afnLLz7m/1/)

You need to call the function using `()`

```
<button ng-repeat="aBtn in myBtns" ng-click="aBtn.action()"> //() here
   {{aBtn.label}}
</button>
```

Your other code didn't work because you were passing the function as a string, i.e.

```
 $scope.myBtns = [
    {
        label: 'btn1',
        action: $scope.restoreDefaults() //pass function, not as '$scope.restoreDefaults()' which is a string
    }
```

Also, for this to work, your function definition should be before this chunk of code, otherwise JS won't register this function. Check [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hnm7eze5/)

Comment: Thank you very much Aniket!

Answer (score 1):

There's an error that the alert is sandboxed. If you really don't need an alert, try to use other mechanism for alert. Your code is working, just change alert to console.log, for example.

Live code: http://jsfiddle.net/b5fmqqen/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $window) {

    $scope.myBtns = [
        {
            label: 'btn1',
            action: function() { 
                console.log('hi') 
                $scope.something = "Yo";
            }
        }
    ];

}
```

Comment: Oh very interesting, can you please explain that sandboxed thing on the alert? I think I ran into it before but didn't understand what was going on, I just found that removing the alert fixed my situation.